# Can we create materialize view on a view

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a view on a mariaDb database which need to be indexed. But only the materialized views can be indexed. So can we create a materialize view from a view?

Comment: Try it.........

Answer (score 1):

So the answer for this is a no.
You cannot create a material view from a view in mariadb